# WhatsApp doesn't open on Android 2.3.6 - says "switch to a supported phone"

Tags: applications, whatsapp-messenger

Whatsapp say app supported to 2020 but won't open from 2018-02-06

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @DanHulme [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/190785/241679) question is asking the same thing just with more detail

Answer (score 1):

According to whatsapp firm :

**Supported devices**
We support all Android phones that meet the following requirements:

Your Android phone is running Android 2.3.3 or later.

Your Android phone is able to receive SMS or calls during the verification process.

You will also need a data plan in order to receive messages when outside the range of a Wi-Fi network.

We only provide limited support to tablet users and we don't support Wi-Fi only devices at this time.

Comment: It seems from the OP that even though according to Whatsapp the app *should* work, nevertheless, it doesn't. And your answer is just proving that WhatsApp should work, it's not actually giving a solution