# Android 2.3.x Gingerbread can't access WhatsApp since 8th Feb 2018

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, 2.3-gingerbread

I've got a Samsung device on Android 2.3.6. The message says the version on my phone became obsolete on Feb 24, 2020, but we are still in 2018. It is asking me to download the latest version.

When I try to do this, it says WhatsApp no longer supports my phone, I should switch to a supported phone.

Comment: Is your phone's date-time correct? It should have shown Feb 1, 2020 not Feb 24, 2020 as per this link: https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/android/26000006/

Comment: Hmm not to burst your bubble but I have a tablet running android 3 and hardly anything works.  Web browser throws certificate errors and lots of other issues. I would switch to another phone if you can.

Answer (score 1):

From WhatsApp's [FAQ](https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/android/26000006/) page:

> For the following platforms, you can no longer create new accounts, nor re-verify existing accounts. **However, you'll be able to continue using WhatsApp**:
>
> - Android versions 2.3.7 and older until February 1, 2020
>
> Note: Because we will no longer actively develop for these platforms, **some features may stop functioning at any time**.

So if you're trying to reverify your account, above is the reason why it won't work.

I remember when WhatsApp stopped supporting some BlackBerrys, some were able to change the date of the phone to a few months earlier, and WhatsApp worked! So go ahead and try that. No guarantee that it's going to work.

If you are still having trouble, contact WhatsApp [support](https://www.whatsapp.com/contact/?subject=messenger) for further assistance.

**Update**

A friend of mine had the same issue, he emailed WhatsApp, and they replied that it was an issue on their side and that it's fixed now.

If it's not fixed on your side, restart your phone and try again.

Answer (score 1):

WhatsApp on Android 2.3.x is still supported, but the support will end next year. I should advise you to upgrade to a more recent phone, say Android 4.0.

However, using your phone native browser,  you can try downloading WhatsApp directly from the [developers' site](https://www.whatsapp.com/android/) (the minimal requirement is Android OS 2.3.3) then enable *Unknown sources*. Install the APK and it should work.

Comment: It's also good to point out that uninstalling WhatsApp before following your steps, is not a good idea, as you can't reverify WhatsApp on those platforms