# i'm not member anymore in groups after moving from the modified to official whatsapp

Tags: applications, root-access, whatsapp-messenger, apk, instant-messaging

I installed whatsapp plus year ago or so. I entered several groups did some conversions. a month ago whenever I press or go to the app it showed me you can't use it anymore after the 1st of April and I have to revert back to the official, but i could get in yet after 1st of April I'm only stuck at that page.
[image]

i tried several thing none of which worked fully and here's what mostly worked

1-I had edited the date so it worked and did a backup and refused to restore it as normal

2-so, I got the whatsapp folder and uninstalled the whatsapp gold
[image]

3-took the files from the `\abo3rabBackup\databases` and put them in `/data/data/com.whatsapp/databases`
and `key` from `\abo3rabBackup\files` to `/data/data/com.whatsapp/files`
`keystore.xml` from `\abo3rabBackup\shared_prefs` to `/data/data/com.whatsapp/shared_prefs`
 
of the official whatsapp newly installed because they seemed from the system I assumed that because the `msgstore.db` was not encrypted

[image][image][image]

4-and whatsapp asked me to set it up once again and I could see all the messages of people and groups again as normal and make a back up although is shows I'm not a member of all these groups anymore

so my question here are there anything that i have to else transfer to make whatsapp recognize I'm in that groups

and thanks for any help and patience in advance

Comment: Would you please mind to translate the first screenshot?

Comment: @Robert the first screenshot seems related to [WhatsApp not supporting older Android version since February 2020](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/190785/cant-access-whatsapp-since-yesterday-8th-feb)

Comment: @Robert it's just a page to direct me to go and tell me how to migrate to the official whatsapp, but I'll translate it anyways. <br/>whatsapp upgrade<br/>the circle: the upgrade is only available on the golden whatsapp plus site(it basically redirects you to their site)<br/>this version became old and you can't use it anymore starting from data and blah blah blah same thing